# How to load external script into Flask app route

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, flask, pyodbc

I need to run my basic script that print data from access data base into my Flask app route. How can i do it?

I was trying to return a script from external file using os.system but id didn't work.

My script:

```py
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\mil0s\Desktop\sklep\sklep.mdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from produkty')

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

My Flask app route:

```py
@app.route("/magazyn")
def magazyn():
    return "?"
```

I just want to show that row values from my script

Comment: Your script code should be in a *function* which returns the values.

Comment: When i made that function I got error: The view function did not return a valid response.
I know that fetchall returnes list of tuples but how can i convert it to variable that will be ok for returning in my app route?